# Getting a AccessToken via Java Swing (Facebook API)

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-access-token

I'm building a Java Application that will connect to the Facebook and get some information. To connect to the Facebook API, Facebook asks for a code called "AccessToken", which you can get when the user connects to your application. My application is running 100% perfect when I already have the AccessToken, but I'm currently getting it externally.

So, I read the Facebook docs and apparently the only way to get the AccessToken is using a Browser, even if it is a Desktop application (like my application). I certainly would not like to run an embbed browser in my application (My objective is to build the entire interface using only Swing components).

So, my question is: In my case, is there a way to me to get this AccessToken without the need of a Browser? Or I REALLY need to embbed a webbrowser in my application or make the user open a browser and get it externally like I'm doing?

Thank you!

Comment: If you need a user access token, you will need to use a browser (or a webview) to get one, there is no other way. But depending on what type of content you want to read, maybe one of the other types of access token (app or page) would suffice.

Comment: @CBroe: Do you know if these other tokens don't need a browser? My app only need to get user's posts and its comments. You know if these tokens would be enough?

Comment: No, for a user’s posts you will need a user access token. (The advantage of an app or page access token would just be, that you need to generate them just once, and not over and over again.)

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks, I get it. I'll have to use a browser, then.